# Need suggestion in Regular expression

Tags: regex

Regular expression:

```
.?Description(?:(?!;).)*|.?Resolution(?:(?!;).)*|.?Root Fix(?:(?!;).)*
```

Input String:

```
" description: this is first line .
this is second line .
this is thrird ;
and this is some random redundant line "
```

Expected output:

```
“description: this is first line .
this is second line .
this is thrird ;”
```

Current output:

```
“description: this is first line .”
```

Could anyone alter this expression to consider anything (blank lines/space) to the left of `;`.

Comment: How to handle newlines depends on which regex dialect or tool you are using. Generally speaking, regex questions should always spell this out; see also the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page:](/tags/regex/info) Please [edit] your question to specify these details.

Comment: `[^;]*` is considerably more economical than `(?:(?!;).)*` and might actually cover newlines as well.

Comment: Thank you .Making this change resolved my issue .

Answer (score 2):

Why not just match everything till `;`

`[\s\S]*;`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/khGH2u/2)

EDIT:

As pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59262079/need-suggestion-in-regular-expression/59262134#comment104732592_59262134), `\S` will also include `;`, so the better approach is:

`[^;]*;`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/khGH2u/3)

Comment: `\S` includes `;` so this is not strictly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the regex:

```
\bDescription\b|\bResolution\b|\bRoot Fix\b\:.*?\;
```

https://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/70

Comment: You have made several assumptions which are not necessarily correct.